# How to release ODBC objects correctly?

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I have created an application that calls `SQLDriverConnect` to connect to a MS SQL Server database called 'MyDB'.  After doing some things, it calls SQLDisconnect.But then SSMS fails to delete 'MyDB'. This means some resources are not closed properly. Only after exiting the process, does SSMS delete it (*i.e.* the OS releases them) and all SQLHENV and SQLHDBC are released properly.
Code below:

```
SMARTHSTMT::~SMARTHSTMT()
{
    if (!m_hstmt) return;
    SQLFreeStmt(m_hstmt, SQL_CLOSE);
    SQLFreeStmt(m_hstmt, SQL_UNBIND);
    SQLFreeStmt(m_hstmt, SQL_RESET_PARAMS);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, m_hstmt);
    m_hstmt = nullptr;
};
```

How can I find which object is not released? Is there any other considerations should I take? any idea or help appreciated.
Edit: code for disconnecting:

```
void AConnection::uDisconnect()
{
    if (m_hdbc)
    {
        SQLDisconnect(m_hdbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_hdbc);
        m_hdbc = nullptr;
    }
    if (m_henv)
    {
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_henv);
        m_henv = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of SQLDisconnect? Your code posted is only about freeing the statement-handle, what about the connection and environment handle?

Comment: They are freed using SQLFreeHandle. I only posted the code for destroying statements because statements are widely used and they it's quite possible to forget freeing them.

Comment: If you free a connection handle, you should get an SQLERROR as return value if there are any open statement handles originating from that connection handle, not?

Comment: YES, I forgot to check the result of SQLDisconnect. It returns SQL_ERROR, there is an active transaction. This sequence of sql command results to an open transaction, the reason is unknown for me. CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX, SQLEndTrans, INSERT INTO, CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX, SQLEndTrans, SQLColumns. At this point SQLDisconnect returns SQL_ERROR, I don't know why SQLColumns begins a transaction. Will you please put this as an answer so that I accept it and the question be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `SQLDisconnect()` returns `SQL_ERROR`. If that is the case, a statement might still be open, or a transaction (as you detected) is still open.

Transaction Handling in ODBC is (simplified) like this:

By default auto-commit is enabled. Everything starts a new transaction and if the statement succeeds the transaction is committed. If you have not changed the commit-mode, its confusing for me that a transaction is still open.

If you have disabled auto-commit, you must manually call `SQLEndTrans(...)` to commit or rollback any ongoing transaction. As far as I know, there is no way in ODBC to query the driver if any transaction is still open.

As you mention the calls to `SQLEndTrans()`, I guess you have already disabled auto-commit. Looking at my sources, I see that I always do a Rollback before closing a connection-handle - maybe because of the same problem, I dont remember exactly (its old code).

Anyway, if you have enabled manual commit mode, I would just recommend that you do a Rollback before closing the connection handle. Maybe there would be tools on the SQL Server Side to analyze more details about what is exactly open at that time..

See here for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131281.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very clear and useful. As you guessed, I disable auto-commit and call SQLEndTrans to commit or rollback. and I decided to rollback befor SQLDisconnect too. This is my last question: why statements such as SQLColumns, SQLTables, SQLStatistics start a transaction?

Comment: @MohamadrezaAbdolahzadeh: I have no idea why the catalog-functions start a transaction. I think I've struggled with the same problem and didnt find any useful solution. Maybe this would be worth to add as stand-alone question.